# MudBlazor Datepicker glithing at top left corner on appearing

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

The date selector in MudBlazor seems to have some issues upon opening. When it was opened it would glitch at the top left corner and then appear the where it soppused to be. Did I do something wrong or is this a bug?

Tried to do use JSinterop to force it to behave the expected way but not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description is kind of vague but I am pretty sure I know what you are talking about. It appears to be a bug with Mudblazor and I have ran into it before.

[Here](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/5450) is the issue on GitHub and someone posted their solution for this:

```
.mud-popover { animation: cssAnimation 0s 0.2s forwards; visibility: hidden; }
@@keyframes cssAnimation { to { visibility: visible; } }
```

This is working for sure but it is sort of a temp fix since it will affect all the popups in MudBlazor. Hopefully they will fix this quick.

Comment: Yeah, solved it. Thx